# Can a Service Worker update itself offline?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, auto-update, bootstrapping

Let's say that I have a service worker that, among other things, helps make a page or application available offline.

Now, the device which runs this application will be offline for a *very* long time. So long, in fact, that (obviously cryptographically signed and verified) updates via sneakernet might even be warranted.

Now, updating the page's *content* is pretty straightforward— but what about **the service worker**? Is there any way for it to update *itself* without a live, genuine HTTP server serving up a fresh Response?

For example, if I have installed the worker originally with [`{updateViaCache: 'all'}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/updateViaCache#:%7E:text=all,-%2Cmeaning), does the service worker itself have any ability to affect the specific cache that `updateViaCache` uses—in essence to "trick" the browser into thinking an update exists?

Comment: If you have a device that's offline anyway, and needs a sneakernet update process, it might be easier to just not use a service worker and instead install a normal http server application on localhost.

Comment: @Bergi The X-Y problem here is a much more horrid and hard-to explain case \(I'm trying to engineer an [actually secure](https://web.archive.org/web/20230625084018/https://www.devever.net/~hl/webcrypto) E2EE chat webapp\). I had hoped to "seal" a secret inside the Service Worker's source code and use it as something like a [TPM's role in AEM](https://blog.invisiblethings.org/2011/09/07/anti-evil-maid.html#:~:text=if%20a%20user%20can,software%20must%20have%20booted). But not trusting the server means vetting an alleged new update, then **client-side** injecting the secret into it before install

Comment: (But I'm also interested in client-software-driven updates of PWAs for a number of other reasons, *including* offline updates.)

Comment: Oh, fancy! Though from what I understand, the TPM should be absolutely read-only, so it wouldn't need updating :-) Not trying to derail the discussion here, it's still an interesting question regardless of the user case

Comment: @Bergi I mean, if nothing else, *security* updates exist \([and for the TPM, too](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-your-security-processor-tpm-firmware-94205cbc-a492-8d79-cc55-1ecd6b0a8022)\). A chat client, E2EE or non, being a user-facing application, will likely need bug fixes or even the most conservative feature updates from time to time.

Comment: @Bergi Now that you imply it, I guess it would be *interesting* to look into having a smaller, HSM-like service worker that doesn't pin the whole application... but what protection would that offer against "the non-secure part" of the application? The site owner could serve up a keylogger and DOM-scraper that sniffs the user's PIN and exfiltrates their whole chat history just the same, right?

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to do the whole anti-evil-maid process where the service worker vets the complete application source code and exposes the verification secret (phrase or image) only when if found everything to be ok. That doesn't prevent the site owner from serving an update, but prevents the user from being unaware of it. That way, for an (acknowledged) update the service worker wouldn't need to update itself, but only the cached resources.